# How can I set an image size fully depending upon ImageSize?

Tags: image

I have an image assigned to `myPicture`

```
myPicture =
```

[image]

```
 Image[myPicture, ImageSize -> {500, 300}]
```

I get result like this, after evaluation:

[image]

My problem is that the image is not fitted to the rectangle. How can I solve that one?

Comment: I think you are over constraining your requirements since the aspect ratio of images is different than the aspect ratio of the space you to put it into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageResize[myPicture, {500, 300}]
```

or

```
Show[myPicture, ImageSize -> {500, 300}, AspectRatio -> 3/5]
```

or, more generally,

```
Show[myPicture, ImageSize -> {500, 300}, AspectRatio -> Full]
```

[image: butterfly]

Comment: I hope you don't mind. I just did not want to waste a new answer to such a one-liner.

Comment: @IstvánZachar No problem - I prefer answers to comments anyway :)

Comment: A good preference, indeed :)